# How to determine size from (nested) std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

New to C++ and trying to wrap my head around initializer_list.

I'm making a Matrix class that effectively stores a 2d array of double values. I don't get the project on a structural level. Like okay we make a Matrix class that essentially stores a 2D array of data. But it needs to be able to store any size array, so it must use a dynamically allocated array. But std::array isn't allowed.

I have no idea how to access the items in the i_list. If they're passed in like

```
Matrix a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

then according to the documentation I've seen, my only options for interaction with that information in the constructor are list.begin() which either points to the {1, 2} and list.end() which points to the  {3,4}

std::vector and std::array are prohibited by the project description, and non-dynamic arrays obviously can't take in variables for size.

So how do I make this able to read a matrix of any size, and how do I take those values from my i_list and store them into something nondynamic?

I'm envisioning something like

```
Matrix::Matrix(const initializer_list & list) {
    double * mat[/*somehow find out size without dynamic allocation*/];
    for (double* i : mat) {
        *i = list[i]; //not how i_list works apparently
    }
}
```

Project description says:
You MAY NOT use library classes such as std::array, std::vector, std::list, etc. for this project. You must implement your Matrix class internally using a dynamically allocated array

Comment: Is the number of inner items variable?

Comment: `std::initializer_list` has `size()` member function that returns the number of elements. It can be iterated over like this: `for (auto& element : list) { /* do something with each element */ }` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to create an array, but not a dynamically allocated one. But I can't create a non-dynamic with a variable passed in for size.

double * arr[list.size()] doesn't work because list.size() isn't a constant.

Comment: As a note: for every object that can be iterated using `begin()`  and `end()` and that is standard complain, the iterator return by `end()` does not point to the last element, but to the element following the last element of the container.

Comment: The way your class is designed, some form of dynamic allocation is inevitable. It could be wrapped in, say, `std::vector` so you don't have explicit `new` calls lying around, but it's still there. You don't know the size of the matrix until runtime; "dynamic allocation" is just a shorter phrase for "memory allocation whose size is not known until runtime".

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, and why I'm struggling so much. Is there a way to use dynamically allocated arrays without std::array?

Comment: It appears you haven't read past the first sentence of my recent comment. I distinctly recall mentioning `std::vector` and `new` there. May I humbly suggest that perhaps it might be of some use to give it a second glance?

Comment: I do say in my post that std::vector and std::array are prohibited by the project description. I appreciate the help you're trying to give and I'm trying my best to understand how to work out a seeming contradiction in the instructions I've been given.

Comment: I distinctly remember mentioning another option beside `std::vector` (and I've never mentioned `std::array` - that one does *not* in fact perform dynamic allocation). So there's still one possibility left. (Though I must say, in my humble opinion your assignment starts the students on the wrong foot; I'd teach `std::vector` early and often.)

Comment: Even if `std::vector` is prohibited, you may implement your vector class, and implement matrix thanks to vector class.

Comment: I guess I don't know the difference between std::vector and a vector class? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Oh my god, DUH. Of course I know that dynamic allocation doesn't need the std. I just wasted 2 days on this. It was so obvious. Grr. Thanks for your patience guys.

Comment: @Reed The difference is that a vector class is a class that wraps a dynamic array allocated with array `new` (or `malloc()`, if you prefer C allocation to C++ allocation), and `std::vector` is a specific vector class provided as a C++ standard library member.  So, if you're not allowed to use `std::vector`, perhaps you're allowed to make your own vector class and use it instead?

Comment: If you do make a vector class, make sure to remember to `delete` the dynamic array it wraps in the destructor, and be careful when reallocating the array to change its size.

Answer (score 3):

`initializer_list`s are very cheap containers of [references to] temporary objects.

You can iterate over them as if they were arrays. In addition they also have a `size()` member so you can query their size.

Here is an example of passing a '2d' `initializer_list` to a function (which could easily be an constructor):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>


using list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<double>;
using list_of_list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<list_of_doubles>;

void info(list_of_list_of_doubles lld)
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (auto& ld : lld) {
        std::cout << "  {";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (auto& d : ld) {
            std::cout << sep << d;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        std::cout << " }\n";
    }

    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    info({
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 }
    });
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  { 1, 2, 3 }
  { 4, 5, 6 }
}
```

> Printing out the contents of the list is pretty simple, but what if I want to save them non-dynamically? I'm making a class constructor, and I want to have access to that data.

OK, so the requirement is that the storage in the class is non-dynamic (i.e. a fixed size).

I am going to make some assumptions:

1. let's say that the target class is a 3x3 matrix
2. any non-specified items in the initializer_list should be assumed to be zero.
3. passing in more than 3 rows or columns is a logic error and should cause an exception to be raised

Here's one (of many) ways:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>


using list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<double>;
using list_of_list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<list_of_doubles>;

struct matrix
{
    matrix(list_of_list_of_doubles lld)
    : _storage {}
    {
        if (lld.size() > 3)
            throw std::invalid_argument("too many rows");
        auto row_idx = std::size_t { 0 };
        for (auto& row : lld) {
            if (row.size() > 3)
                throw std::invalid_argument("too many columns");
            std::copy(std::begin(row), std::end(row), std::begin(_storage[row_idx]));
            ++row_idx;
        }
    }

    double _storage[3][3];
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix& m)
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (auto& ld : m._storage) {
        std::cout << "  {";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (auto& d : ld) {
            std::cout << sep << d;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        std::cout << " }\n";
    }

    return std::cout << "}";
}

int main()
{
    matrix m({
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4.1, 5.2, 6.3 },
        { 2.01, 4.5 }  // ,0
    });
    std::cout << m << std::endl;

}
```

> but I wanted a dynamically-sized 2-d array...

Oh go on then...

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>


using list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<double>;
using list_of_list_of_doubles = std::initializer_list<list_of_doubles>;

std::size_t total_extent(const list_of_list_of_doubles& lld)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(lld), std::end(lld), std::size_t(0),
                           [](auto tot, auto& container) {
                               return tot + container.size();
                           });

}

struct matrix
{
    using value_storage = std::unique_ptr<double[]>;
    using index_storage = std::unique_ptr<std::size_t>;

    matrix(list_of_list_of_doubles lld)
    : _total_extent { total_extent(lld) }
    , _rows { lld.size() }
    , _indecies { new std::size_t[_rows] }
    , _storage { new double [_total_extent] }
    {
        auto istorage = _storage.get();
        auto iindex = _indecies.get();
        for (auto& row : lld) {
            *iindex++ = istorage - _storage.get();
            istorage = std::copy(std::begin(row), std::end(row), istorage);
        }
    }

    std::size_t rows() const {
        return _rows;
    }

    const double* column(std::size_t row) const {
        return std::addressof(_storage[_indecies[row]]);
    }

    std::size_t column_size(std::size_t row) const {
        return row == _rows - 1
        ? _total_extent - _indecies[row]
        : _indecies[row + 1] - _indecies[row];
    }

    std::size_t _total_extent, _rows;
    std::unique_ptr<std::size_t[]> _indecies;
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> _storage;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix& m)
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (std::size_t row = 0 ; row < m.rows() ; ++row) {
        std::cout << "  {";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (std::size_t col = 0 ; col < m.column_size(row) ; ++col) {
            std::cout << sep << m.column(row)[col];
            sep = ", ";
        }
        std::cout << " }\n";
    }

    return std::cout << "}";
}

int main()
{
    matrix m({
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4.1, 5.2, 6.3 },
        { 2.01, 4.5 }  // ,0
    });
    std::cout << m << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Printing out the contents of the list is pretty simple, but what if I want to save them non-dynamically? I'm making a class constructor, and I want to have access to that data. That's the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: unfortunately setting it as a 3x3 seems to just be reinforcing my fear that it's impossible to take in an initializer_list of any size and store that data without std::array or std::vector.

Project description says: You MAY NOT use library classes such as std::array, std::vector, std::list, etc. for this project. You must implement your Matrix class internally using a dynamically allocated array

Comment: @Reed ok, so you'll need to use std::unique_ptr<T[]>. If I showed you how to do that, I'd be doing your assignment for you :)

Comment: @Reed third and final update gives you dynamic memory management. If you show this to your tutor he will absolutely know that you have been on stack overflow, so be wise about it and learn why I have done what I have done...

Comment: I appreciate it, @Richard. I figured out a simpler way to do it that didn't involve 'unique_ptr'.

Came out to a probably inefficient but definitely fully understood implementation.

Comment: @Reed cool. if you didn't use unique_ptr, be careful of memory leaks in the destructor and assignment operator.

Comment: That's what I'm troubleshooting right now! But I think that deserves its own thread if I have much more trouble with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking for something like this:

```
struct Matrix {
  Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> m) {
    int max=0;
    for (auto l: m)
      if (m.size()>max)
        max= m.size();
    std::cout << "your matriz seems to be: " 
              << m.size() << ' ' << max << std::endl;
  }
};
```